# Directive changes color and text on a fly

Tags: angularjs-directive

This is a directive that should change the color and text of the element depending on the incoming data

```
function colorStatus() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {
                status: '@'
            },
            link: function (scope, element) {
            let status = +scope.status;
            switch (status) {
                case 0:
                    element.text(' ');
                    element.css('color', '#FFFFFF');
                    break;
                case 1:
                    element.text('Correct!');
                    element.css('color', '#4CAF50');
                    break;
                case 2:
                    element.text('Error!');
                    element.css('color', '#F44336');
                    break;
                case 3:
                    element.text('Waiting...');
                    element.css('color', '#FF9800');
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Initially, it receives resolved data from the controller.

Here is HTML:

```
<color-status status="{{vm.status}}"></color-status>
<button ng-click="vm.changeStatus()"><button>
```

Here is function from controller:

```
vm.changeStatus = changeStatus;
vm.status = chosenTask.status;  // It equals 0 in the received data

function changeStatus() {
    vm.status = 1;
}
```

I expect that the text and color of the directive will change, but this does not happen. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

## Post link is only called once

The problem you're having is that you set your element's text and color in your `link` function. This means that when your directive instantiates and goes through initialisation, the `link` function will be executed, but it will get executed exactly once. When the value of `status` changes, you're not handling those changes to reflect the, on your element. Therefore you should add `$onChanges()` function to your directive and handle those changes.

```
function StatusController($element) {
    this.$element = $element;
    this.status = 0;
}

StatusController.mapper = [
    { text: ' ', color: '#FFFFFF' },
    { text: 'Correct!', color: '#4CAF50' },
    { text: 'Error!', color: '#F44336' },
    { text: 'Waiting...', color: '#FF9800' },
}];

StatusController.prototype.setStatus = function(status) {
    var statusObj = StatusController.mapper[+status];
    this.$element
        .text(statusObj.text)
        .css('color', statusObj.color);
}

StatusController.prototype.$onInit = function() {
    // this.status is now populated by the supplied attribute value
    this.setStatus(this.status);
}

StatusController.prototype.$onChanges = function(changes) {
    if (changes.status && !changes.status.isFirstChange()) {
        this.setStatus(this.status);
    }
}

var StatusDirective = {
    restrict: 'AE',
    controller: StatusController,
    scope: true,
    bindToController: {
        status: '@'
    }
};

angular.module('someModule')
       .directive('colorStatus', function() { return StatusDirective; });
```

But apart from this, I also suggest you set element's text by using `ng-bind` or `{{...}}` to put that value in. Directive could populate its public properties instead and use those in HTML along with CSS. It's always wiser to **not** manipulate DOM elements from within AngularJS code if possible.

```
function StatusController($element) {
    this.$element = $element;
    this.status = 0;
    this.text = '';
    this.name = '';
}

StatusController.mapper = [
    { text: ' ', name: '' },
    { text: 'Correct!', name: 'correct' },
    { text: 'Error!', name: '#error' },
    { text: 'Waiting...', name: 'pending' },
}];

StatusController.prototype.setStatus = function(status) {
    var statusObj = StatusController.mapper[+status];
    this.text = statusObj.text;
    this.name = statusObj.name;
}

StatusController.prototype.$onInit = function() {
    // this.status is now populated by the supplied attribute value
    this.setStatus(this.status);
}

StatusController.prototype.$onChanges = function(changes) {
    if (changes.status && !changes.status.isFirstChange()) {
        this.setStatus(this.status);
    }
}

var StatusDirective = {
    restrict: 'AE',
    controller: StatusController,
    controllerAs: 'colorStatus',
    scope: true,
    bindToController: {
        status: '@'
    }
};

angular.module('someModule')
       .directive('colorStatus', function() { return StatusDirective; });
```

And then in your template write use it this way:

```
<color-status status="{{vm.status}}" ng-class="colorStatus.name" ng-bind="colorStatus.text"></color-status>
```

This will give you a lot more flexibility in templates. Instead of setting text in the controller you could get away with just class name and use pseudo classes to add text to the element however you please to do, so each instance of your `<color-status>` directive could then display differently for the same status value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I am very new in the angularjs, so could you show me how to do it, please?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not use components in my project so I can not find the way to use $onInit or $onChange. But any way thanks a lot for your time and answers.

Comment: @MyroslavPasko This is not a component. It's a directive... These lifecycle hooks are part of directive controller. **And you can easily use them**, although your directive would be better off being a component as you're using it as an element anyway. But you don't have to naturally.